# Theme layout update file is not valid after changing to developer mode

Tags: magento2, layout, developer-mode

After i changed my site to developer mode, i got this error while trying to access backend module:

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Theme layout
>   update file
>   '/var/www/project/app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml'
>   is not valid. Premature end of data in tag page line 3  Line: 7

**/var/www/project/app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think missing page tag close

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
</head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code for your layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```